# In Asp.Net MVC applications, are objects that were allocated during a request immediately deallocated when the request finishes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, garbage-collection

After reviewing a few MSDN docs

[Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Garbage Collection and Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764(v=vs.110).aspx)

I'm still curious about the nature of request threads in IIS when hosting an MVC web application. It's my understanding that these threads are recycled and not necessarily allocated and deallocated with each request.

Are objects that are allocated during a given web request deallocated when the request ends or could they still potentially be around long after the request finishes (even though they are not referenced)?

Comment: In general, the garbage collector can clean up any no-longer-referenced object at any time and isn't under any obligation to do so for any particular object at any particular time.  This is fine for pure .NET objects, as they'll get cleaned up when memory gets tight, but objects that wrap native resources may need to be explicitly disposed by your code so they release the resources in a timely manner.  Objects that need this typically implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @adv12 Right, I have an intermediate understanding of how garbage collection works. I'm just wondering if it takes advantage of the request-based nature of Asp.Net to collect Gen 0 objects quickly after the request ends. There is a framework we're using that is unnecessarily creating many small objects. Wondering if I should put it on the backlog to refactor the code or not.

Comment: I would be surprised if the .NET garbage collector gives ASP.NET special treatment.

Comment: Can you leverage the controller being disposed for cleanup? Because, it is disposed after view render. I'm not sure about the particulars of your problem so I can't say if its appropriate.I would be very surprised if there was an explicit collection after every request. In fact, it would negatively impact performance!

Comment: @ChiralMichael Not really, because they are managed objects which do not implement IDisposable and thus cannot be manually deallocated/cleaned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that the framework isn't doing anything special here. Combing the MVC source code shows that neither is ASP/MVC. The only forced collections are during unit testing.